# how to get element value by knowing parent's name of another parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

let's say the I have 2 textareas with the same ID and their parents have their same ID, But the parent forms with different NAMES.. and I need to get the value of second textarea of the second form!!! 
here's a simple code..

```js
var formX = document.getElementsByName("form2");
  for(i = 0; i < formX.length; i++){
    if(formX[i].type == "textarea"){
      var inputval = formX.value;
      alert(inputval);
    }
  }
```

```html
<form name="form1">
  <div id="samediv1">
    <div id="samediv2">
      <textarea id="sameID">value1</textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<form name="form2">
  <div id="samediv1">
    <div id="samediv2">
      <textarea id="sameID">value2</textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

- When I tried it, no alert appears, and I know that because the loop didn't find any text areas because it is inside another element(s) within the form..
  So, how to go deep in parents and childs?!!

thanks a lot

Comment: same id's for two element is un-recognisable when you are going to deal them with javascript/jQuery.

Comment: Use classes instead of ids. `id` is unique identifier for a particular element

Comment: You should not have multiple elements with the same `id`. The idea of `id` is to provide an unique id to the elements within the document.

Comment: I know it's sooooo dummy using same ID for 2 or more element, it's against the idea of ID... but my project it kinda integration script, so I cant change the source code

Comment: If you can inject a script, you can always change the code ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the same by using jQuery `find()` or `children()` method. Here You can read about [jQuery Traversing](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_traversing.asp).

```js
console.log($('[name=form2]').find('#sameID').text()); //or value() can be used in place of text() method
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form1">
  <div id="samediv1">
    <div id="samediv2">
      <textarea id="sameID">value1</textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<form name="form2">
  <div id="samediv1">
    <div id="samediv2">
      <textarea id="sameID">value2</textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Welcome Hossam..! Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

There is no purpose of giving same ID to two different elements. You are messing with the concept of using IDs. Try different IDs and it will work. 
For eg:

```
$('#parentId').find('#childId');
```

or

```
$('#parentId #childId');
```

Answer (score 0):

Youn get second textarea value using single line of code. where is no need to use any id. check updated snippet below..

```js
console.log($('form[name="form2"] textarea').val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form1">
  <div id="samediv1">
    <div id="samediv2">
      <textarea id="sameID">value1</textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<form name="form2">
  <div id="samediv1">
    <div id="samediv2">
      <textarea id="sameID">value2</textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use pure js to get value from desired textarea

```js
var forms = document.getElementsByTagName('form');

for(var i = 0, ii = forms.length; i < ii; i++) {
  var textArea = forms[i].getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0];
  console.log(textArea.value)
}
```

```html
<form name="form1">
  <div id="samediv1">
    <div id="samediv2">
      <textarea id="sameID">value1</textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<form name="form2">
  <div id="samediv1">
    <div id="samediv2">
      <textarea id="sameID">value2</textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code

```
val2 = $("form[name=form2] #samediv2 textarea").val()
```

The above code will return value as `value2`

Hope this helps